# ORMLite: How to join two tables without foreign key

Tags: sqlite, ormlite

I have to join two independent tables in `sqlite`. They don't have any foreign key relationship.

Example:

- Table A has a field `name`
- Table B has a field `primaryName`

I want to do something like

```
select A.* from A inner join B on A.name = B.primaryName
    where A.id = 10 and B.address is null
```

`ORMLite` enforces foreign key, is there a way to do this in `ORMLite`?

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately the short answer is "not at this time".  You can certainly use the raw query functionality to support this:

> http://ormlite.com/docs/raw-queries

**Edit:**

This has [finally] been added ORMLite.  It has been checked into trunk and will be in version 4.49.  Here's the check-in on github:

> https://github.com/j256/ormlite-core/commit/b37914d76fbbbbbc70d473be1cf1b6de19b847f5

Comment: Even with raw query, a foreign key relationship needs to be defined. Otherwise the raw query doesn't return any result.

Comment: It would be sufficient if there is something like `queryBuilder.rawFrom("A inner join B on A.name = B.primaryName")`. But using current raw query kills me since the result list if of Object[] type.

Comment: This is a great new feature. Thanks @Gray. I wonder why the gradle bundle for ormlite-android v4.49 is not available and if it will be available anytime soon?

Comment: @nemo it is available here ormlite.com/releases but only as a Snapshot