# How to generate JOIN ON query using ORMLite

Tags: ormlite, join

I would like to JOIN 2 tables using ORMLite while there is no [ORMLite's foreign key](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#foreign%28%29) definition between the tables.

To better explain my problem, the query I want ORMLite to generate should look like this:

```
SELECT Order.ID
FROM Order
JOIN MyTmpTable
ON Order.CustomerID=MyTmpTable.CustomerID;
```

Unfortunately, the [join(...)](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/stmt/QueryBuilder.html#join%28com.j256.ormlite.stmt.QueryBuilder%29) method available in ORMLite requires explicit [foreign key](http://ormlite.com/javadoc/ormlite-core/com/j256/ormlite/field/DatabaseField.html#foreign%28%29) definition between the tables.

> Join with another query builder. This will add into the SQL something
>   close to " INNER JOIN other-table ...". Either the object associated
>   with the current QueryBuilder or the argument QueryBuilder **must have a
>   foreign field of the other one**. An exception will be thrown otherwise.

But neither `Order` nor `MyTmpTable` has foreign key definition. MyTmpTable definition is the following:

```
@DatabaseTable
class MyTmpTable {
    ...
    @DatabaseField
    private Long longId;
    ...
}
```

And I really can't change it to

```
@DatabaseTable
class MyTmpTable {
    ...
    @DatabaseField(foreign = true)
    private Order order;
    ...
}
```

because it serves as a generic temporary join table.

Something like `joinOn(...)` would solve my problem, but it is probably not available in ORMLite.

Have you any ideas how could I join 2 tables with no foreign attribute defined?

Comment: Uff, I just found a sad answer: JOIN ON is NOT SUPPORTED!

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410674/ormlite-how-to-join-two-tables-without-foreign-key

Comment: In case someone finds this - an answer has been provided here - the join feature (without needing foreign key relations afaik) has been added: http://stackoverflow.com/a/15418795/1041533