# How to join two tables in ORMLite without a foreign key relationship?

Tags: android, sqlite, join, foreign-key-relationship, ormlite

I have gone through many posts including the one in stack overflow.
[ORMLite: How to join two tables without foreign key](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15410674/ormlite-how-to-join-two-tables-without-foreign-key)

It clearly states that we can't achieve that. But that would make the framework so incomplete and un usable.

**Are there any new methods introduced to achieve the same?**
I have gone through ORMLite raw queries as well but could't find a viable solution.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

It can be achieved through **rawQuery**.

Comment: Only if there is a foreign key relation between the tables as it seems. At least I had no luck with rawQuery. The new support for join query without the foreign relations requirement added by Gray in 4.49 works though.